# Only allow specific regions to be selected in Azure

Tags: azure

I'm trying to force anyone that is provisioning resources or services in Azure to only be able to select a specific region(s). For example, when they provision a resource group, the dropdown only shows a specific region(s). I was hoping there is some global setting that will affect all users. We are also using Azure AD; does that help or matter? I tried searching the Azure docs and the PowerShell commands, but I just can't find any mention of this setting.

Comment: This might help: https://richardjgreen.net/restricting-azure-resource-deployment-region/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Azure Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/overview) to do it.

Here is a sample policy requires that all resources are deployed to the approved location, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/allowed-locs), you could try to [deploy with portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/allowed-locs#deploy-with-the-portal) or [with powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/allowed-locs#deploy-with-powershell).

> This policy requires that all resources are deployed to the approved locations. You specify an array of approved locations.

Sample template:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "Allowed locations",
    "policyType": "BuiltIn",
    "description": "This policy enables you to restrict the locations your organization can specify when deploying resources. Use to enforce your geo-compliance requirements.",
    "parameters": {
      "listOfAllowedLocations": {
        "type": "Array",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The list of locations that can be specified when deploying resources.",
          "strongType": "location",
          "displayName": "Allowed locations"
        }
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "not": {
          "field": "location",
          "in": "[parameters('listOfAllowedLocations')]"
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "Deny"
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/e56962a6-4747-49cd-b67b-bf8b01975c4c",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
  "name": "e56962a6-4747-49cd-b67b-bf8b01975c4c"
}
```

Comment: Thank you both for your help! You both help me solve my problem and I appreciate it.